# Format not supported or reader plugin not found, Fiji ImageJ

Tags: format, tiff, imagej, fiji

I have just downloaded Fiji **on Linux** 64 bits for visualizing **ome.tif files**. I haven't modified any setting but it can't open my files.

I am getting the error "Format not supported or reader plugin not found". The console indicates: "io.scif.FormatException: Invalid TIFF file".

It doesn't work either on ImageJ.

Do you know how could my problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your ome.tif files are malformed or not actually in the format you think they are.

Check for any weird settings in the programs where they were generated, or if the files got damaged during transference (to a pendrive or something) with checksums.

If you are dragging the files to your ImageJ/FIJI window, try instead to open them via Plugins-->Bio-formats-->Bio-formats Importer and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both dragging and opening via File --> Open but it's not working. When I use Plugins-->Bio-formats-->Bio-formats Importer it's not working. However, when I use File-->Import-->Image sequence it works.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Bio-formats should be able to handle multi-slice stacks or hyperstacks perfectly. Maybe your files are secretly .zip files in disguise? In any way, I'm glad you found a way!